# connecting to db2 through pdo_ibm module manually configured error SQL10007N -5005

Tags: php, pdo, db2

I am having difficulties to connect to remote db2 database using pdo_ibm, I followed the instructions on IBM to configure the pdo_ibm library and linux client  but since my php is not configured manually but installed through apt-get I am not sure if current error might be due to a missconfiguration or anything else.

My stage is: 
    Linux debian wheezy
    ibm db2 client 10.5
    php 5.4.45
    pdo_ibm 1.4

when I try to connect with db2 with the following code:

```
<?php
$usernameMaximo = '@user';
$passwordMaximo = '@password';
$connectionStringMaximo = 'ibm:DRIVER={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};DATABASE=@databaseName;HOSTNAME=@xx.xxx.xxx.xx;PORT=50002;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;';
try {
  $connection = new PDO($connectionStringMaximo, $usernameMaximo, $passwordMaximo, array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)
  );
  echo "Success";
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e);
}
```

I get the following error

```
object(PDOException)[2]
  protected 'message' => string 'SQLSTATE=     , SQLDriverConnect: -5005 [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL10007N Message "0" could not be retrieved.  Reason code: "3".
' (length=123)
  private 'string' (Exception) => string '' (length=0)
  protected 'code' => int 0
  protected 'file' => string '/apps/html/tests/pdo_db2.php' (length=28)
  protected 'line' => int 8
  private 'trace' (Exception) => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=6)
          'file' => string '/apps/html/tests/pdo_db2.php' (length=28)
          'line' => int 8
          'function' => string '__construct' (length=11)
          'class' => string 'PDO' (length=3)
          'type' => string '->' (length=2)
          'args' => 
            array (size=4)
              ...
  private 'previous' (Exception) => null
  public 'errorInfo' => null
```

network/firewall is already check so I can connect through squirrel client, Anyone has faced the same problem?

Comment: If you have access to db2diag.log on the server, check for any error. I assume that in Squirrel the same port was used.

Comment: @data_henrik yes same port is used in squirrel, I do not think that the connection is even reaching the server but I will try to recover log file .

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried the alternative way provided [here](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-ibm.connection.php)

The following example shows a PDO_IBM DSN for connecting to an DB2 database cataloged as DB2_MAXIMO in db2cli.ini:

```
$db = new PDO("ibm:DSN=DB2_MAXIMO", "", "");

[DB2_MAXIMO]
Database=SAMPLE
Protocol=TCPIP
Port=50002
Hostname=my-db2-machine
UID=my-OS-user
PWD=my-OS-password
```

Answer (score 3):

Can you try to set the right NCIM instance name? by default:

```
 DB2INSTANCE=db2inst1
```

To know if db2inst1 is the right name of DB2 instance, execute:

```
sudo su db2inst1
db2level
```

Response could be something like this:

```
DB21085I Instance "db2inst1" uses "64" bits and DB2 code release "SQL09074"
with level identifier "08050107".
Informational tokens are "DB2 v9.7.0.4", "s110330", "IP23243", and Fix Pack "4".
Product is installed at "/opt/ibm/db2/V9.7".
```

Comment: How can you set this instance using the IBM ODBC CLIDRIVER?

https://github.com/php/pecl-database-pdo_ibm 

https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/data/db2/drivers/odbc_cli/